# how to call update file in ajax on index.php page

Tags: php, ajax, onbeforeunload

**update.php page**

```
if (isset($_POST['bags']))
{
    $bagS=$_POST['bags'];
        $id=$_POST["id"];
        $_SESSION['id']=$id;
        $cats = explode(" ", $bagS);
        $cats = preg_split('/,/', $bagS, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        foreach($cats as $key => $cat )
        {
        $cat  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$cats[$key]);
        $cat = trim($cat);
 if($cat !=NULL)
             {
                 $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE wallet SET `Status`="Hold" where `Id`=? AND `bags`="'.$cat.'" ');
                 $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["id"]);
                 $stmt->execute();

  }
  }
}
```

**want to use update.php file on index.php page on `window.onbeforeunload`**

**using ajax here**

```
function myfoo(){

    $.ajax({
                url: "update.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {id: 1},
                success: function (r) {}
    });
        }

        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
      myfoo();
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    };
```

Comment: what is problem with your code ? where your facing issue ?

Comment: i want to execute update query if browser close or click back button by user. iam using update.php and index.php file .so how to call update.php file on index.php when window.onbeforeunload fires

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript, browsers, window close - send an AJAX request or run a script on window closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162188/javascript-browsers-window-close-send-an-ajax-request-or-run-a-script-on-win)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) your not sending any data like **bags**

2) ajax not defined  **type:'post'**   but your accessing value by post . if you not define the type means ajax will use default get method .

```
$.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            type:'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: 1,bags:bags}, // bags collection value what your goging to send to server 
            success: function (r) {}
});
```

Comment: iam also using  $id=$_POST["id"]; so id: 1 means in Ajax?

Comment: id: 1 is equal to   id=1  you can access it in php side like this $_POST['id']   ... data:{name:value,name1:value1....}

Comment: still not working. is right code of window.onbeforeunload..            function myfoo(){
          $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            type:'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: 1,bags:bags}, // bags collection value what your goging to send to server 
            success: function (r) {}
});
    }
 
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  myfoo();
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};

Comment: is there any error in console tab ? did you included jquery ? @krishna

Comment: in <head> using    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: and there is no warning or alert message when click close ..it directly closing the browser

Answer (score 0):

working code just change one thing in it. Thanks @JYoThI https://stackoverflow.com/users/5933698/jyothi

```
$.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            type:'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                on_timeout: 1 // i just add this line
            },
 // bags collection value what your goging to send to server 
            success: function (r) {}
});
```