# Javascript not working on mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this js that requests the user to be logged out whenever they close the tab/window and cancels that request when the user does an `window.onload` shortly after a few second to distinguish between refresh and exiting the tab/window. it works perfectly when on Chrome but when it comes to mozilla the `window.onunload` event gets triggered but does not trigger the ajax call. below are my codes

```
window.onunload = function(){

setCookie('tabs', parseInt(getCookie('tabs')) - 1, 99999)
if(parseInt(getCookie('tabs')) < 1)
{
if (window.localStorage) {
        window.localStorage['myUnloadEventFlag']=new Date().getTime();
    }
    requestSessionTimeout();

}
};



window.onload = function(){
    setCookie('tabs', parseInt(getCookie('tabs')) + 1, 99999)   
    if(parseInt(getCookie('tabs')) < 2 ){
        if (window.localStorage) {
            var t0 = Number(window.localStorage['myUnloadEventFlag']);
            if (isNaN(t0)){
                t0=0;
            } 
            var t1=new Date().getTime();
            var duration=t1-t0;
            if (duration<10*1000) {
                cancelSessionTimeoutRequest(); // asynchronous AJAX call
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and here are the cancelSessionTimeoutRequest and requestSessionTimeout definitions

```
function requestSessionTimeout(){
    var header = ''
    var token = ''

$.ajax({
        url:antiCsrfHost +"/addSessionToDeleteQueue",
        type:"POST",
        aysnc:false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success:function(d){
        }
    })
}

function cancelSessionTimeoutRequest(){
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: antiCsrfHost + '/csrf' ,
        xhrFields: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        aysnc:true,
        success: function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                    url:antiCsrfHost +"/removeSessionToDeleteQueue",
                    type:"POST",
                    data : null,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    aysnc:true,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    beforeSend : function(xhr){
                          xhr.setRequestHeader(data.headerName, data.token);
                         },
                    success:function(d){

                    }
                })
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: firefox should be throwing a javascript error on the console, be sure to check it.

Comment: I dont get to see the console since the part where it goes wrong is on exit of the window plus the debugger dosent seem to stop even when it goes through

Comment: Try with window.onbeforeunload.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6162238/1514875

Answer (score 0):

Hey your code working on Google Chrome but not working on Mozilla....

Solution 1:

Means there may be a cache problem first you clear cache then relaoad your webpage

Or

Solution 2:

```
        event.preventDefault();
```

Write this code inside windowonload function

Comment: adding `event.preventDefault();` worked perfectly for me sir! though i still dont know why it behaves differently between firefox and chrome

Comment: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered