# Can't post a httpClient request when call before unload

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

My problem is that when i call a function who listen to the event onBeforeUnload(), i want to post a data with a httpClient request. The problem is that my request is not sent. Here the code

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeUnload(): void {
     this._httpClient.post(`${localhost:8080/apiRest}`, infoIWantToSent).subscribe();
  }
```

I don't know if this is the good way to follow. Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: what is `httpClient`?

Comment: `navigator.sendBeacon` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48961026/14357

Comment: it is a service to use http protocol https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use ngOnDestroy?

```
export class NewComponent implements OnDestroy{
    ngOnDestroy() {
            this._httpClient.post(${localhost:8080/apiRest}, infoIWantToSent).subscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this answer help? @scavengers

Comment: I can't see how this might help. The browser window is about to close. Anything async will be destroyed before it completes, probably even before anything is sent. In 2018 (if you don't need to support Internet Explorer), [`navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) is the way forward here.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer. the OnDestroy does'nt work in my case (never call). I find a solution by using :

`@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeUnload(): void { 
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST',`${localhost:8080/apiRest`, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    return  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(infoIWantToSent));
  }`
It's seems work. the token is the connexion token of my application.

Comment: Be aware that synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` is being phased out. There's a deprecation warning [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request) This solution could stop working at any time.

Comment: How do we make a synchronous request without XMLHttpRequest ?

Comment: You don't. Blocking in JavaScript a bad idea, which is why this is being phased out in the first place. The way to solve this, as said before, is using  `navigator.sendBeacon`. Here's [a good write-up](https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/09/beacon-api.html) on the motivation behind `sendBeacon` (it's directly related to the problem that you are currently trying to solve). It seems like a no-brainer to me, unless you need to support Internet Explorer, in which case, use [a polyfill](https://github.com/miguelmota/Navigator.sendBeacon)