# Check user active status

Tags: javascript, php

is there a way to check if the user is inactive? I'm using vanilla php.

I want the user to log out if the user closes the window, so that it will reflec that they are inactive.

i tried using window.addEventListener('beforeunload', logout), but didn't work.

Comment: If u only want check if hes actve or not there is similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162188/javascript-browsers-window-close-send-an-ajax-request-or-run-a-script-on-win

Answer (score 2):

The reason `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', logout)` does not work is you are not allowed to do any asynchronous task when the user closes the browser/tab since, sadly, such a thing could be used maliciously by the dark side of the internet.

Besides, the user has closed the tab, they expect it to close immediately and not wait for your app to do something. Which is why that approach is prevented by browsers.

On top of that, what if they just turn off their computer or kill the browser? And what if they have your site open in two tabs (browsing different pages at the same time)? Closing one would log them out of the other!

One approach is to instead have regular pings from the application to the back end to keep their session alive. It would ping an endpoint you would create on the back end via a `fetch()` call in the JS on a periodic basis using `setInterval()`. The back end, upon receiving this request, would extend the session expiry time by the same period (plus a little buffer). This is sometimes called a "keep-alive". If it is not received, the session will simply expire.

However, since tabs that are not currently visible (in modern browsers) can be put forcibly put to sleep by the browser to save processor time/battery life of people's machines, this would also mean they would be unavoidably logged out if the tab was left idle in the background for that earlier mentioned period (which is of your choosing) and not just when they close the tab. If this is fine, then this approach is valid. But you only usually see this approach therefore on websites where security is very high like banking websites.

If that is a problem the only way of doing it is to migrate your entire session logic to use `sessionStorage` instead of cookies. `sessionStorage` is a browser feature that allows arbitrary data to be stored only for as long as there is at least one tab with your site open. But if you are using cookies, the entire auth mechanism and logon screens would need to be rewritten. It would touch both the back end and front end.

As you can tell, all of this is a big hassle. Thats why most websites just simply set a sensible static session expiry time and that's it. Logging out on tab close is more annoying to the user than useful unless this is a high security application, and you'll notice most websites do not do this.