# Sending a post Request with Javascript on unload/beforeunload. Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, http-post

Added: I cannot use jQuery. I am using a Siemens S7 control unit which has a tiny webserver that cannot even handle a 80kB jQuery file, so I can only use native Javascript. from this link [Ajax request with JQuery on page unload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821625/ajax-request-with-jquery-on-page-unload) I get that I need to make the request synchronous instead of asynchronous. Can that be done with native Javascript?

I copied the code from here: [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

I was wondering if I could call this on closing the window/tab/leaving the site with jquery beforeunload or unload. Should be possible, right?

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
<body onunload="Exit()" onbeforeunload="Exit()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Exit()
        {
            Stop();
            document.body.onunload       = "";
            document.body.onbeforeunload = "";
            // Make sure it is not sent twice
        }
        function Stop()
        {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("POST","some_path",false);
            request.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.send("some_arg="+some_arg);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Note that the request probably has to be synchronous (call `request.open` with `async=false`).

**One additional notable point of attention:**

If the client is terminated abruptly (e.g., browser is closed with "End Process" or "Power Down"), then neither the `onunload` event nor the `onbeforeunload` will be triggered, and the request will not be sent to the server.

Comment: This is now [blocked in Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4664843055398912). For simple use cases (i.e. posting analytics from a major browser) you can now use navigator.sendBeacon().

Comment: NB: The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) explicitly advise _against_ using `sendBeacon` with `beforeunload` and `unload` events